# History of opened folders in File Explorer

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

I'd like to see history of folders I've opened in File Explorer.

For example yesterday I had 8 folders opened at the time I've turned off my machine, if I could see and open them again today, much like browsers session/history manager plugins, I'd be more productive.

I'm on Windows 10 by the way.

Comment: you have to first enable extended logging to get access time loged

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a built-in capability within Windows 10 that can help you in this area.  You can create a shortcut to your **Recent Items** that will show you the files and folders you have recently accessed:

1. Create a desktop shortcut to `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\` and name it `Recent Items`
2. Copy that shortcut to `%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`
3. Right-click the shortcut on the `All Apps` list and select `Pin to start`

When you utilize that shortcut to open your Recent Items window, you can sort it by the `Date Modified` column or you can even right-click the top row and add the `Date Accessed` column. This should give you something rather close to what you want to see.

Comment: That's pretty cool, if only "Type" column be different for each item type. They are all "Shortcut" and I can't separate folders and files.

Comment: Needless to say, whatever you prefer.  The `Recent Items` folder *does* include both files and folders, but is also very comprehensive since it defaults to showing the last 150 items accessed.  As other contributors have already mentioned, anything else will probably involve either in-depth logging or third-party software.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for the information.  I can confirm that this folder is what drives the "Quick access" feature in file explorer, so you can use the contents of this folder to manipulate what appears in quick access.

Comment: If you already have Windows Explorer pinned to the task bar, you can also browse to that shortcut then drag the folder onto the pinned Explorer icon and drop it to pin it to the jump list

Answer (score 4):

You can display the recent files/folders very easily without creating a shortcut, just invoke the command **shell:recent** in run box
Win+R shell:recent

Comment: Would be great if you could also mention the Windows Versions running on both the PC and Laptop, and if you could see both the devices in the Personal hotspot connections on the Android and the IPs they are getting.

Answer (score 4):

There are two other `CLSID`s defined under `HKLM\CLSID` that provide filtered views of the items in `shell:Recent`:

- **Recent Folders**: `{22877a6d-37a1-461a-91b0-dbda5aaebc99}`
- **Recent Items Instance Folder** (files): `{4564b25e-30cd-4787-82ba-39e73a750b14}`

Entries can be created under `HKCU` that modify these definitions to add them to the Navigation Pane.

1. Add the `System.IsPinnedToNameSpaceTree` DWORD with a value of **`1`** to the definition
2. Add the CLSID to the Desktop namespace
3. Specify a display name and icon under `HKCU\...\Explorer\CLSID`

The following can be copied into a text editor & saved as a `.reg` file to add `Recent Folders` to the Navigation Pane:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\{22877a6d-37a1-461a-91b0-dbda5aaebc99}]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CLSID\{22877a6d-37a1-461a-91b0-dbda5aaebc99}]
@="Recent Folders"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CLSID\{22877a6d-37a1-461a-91b0-dbda5aaebc99}\DefaultIcon]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,\
  00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,69,00,\
  6d,00,61,00,67,00,65,00,72,00,65,00,73,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,2d,\
  00,31,00,31,00,37,00,00,00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{22877a6d-37a1-461a-91b0-dbda5aaebc99}]
@="Recent Folders"
"System.IsPinnedToNamespaceTree"=dword:00000001
```

And this `.reg` file will add `Recent Files` and increase the number of files displayed from the Quick Access default of 25 to 50:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\{4564b25e-30cd-4787-82ba-39e73a750b14}]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CLSID\{4564b25e-30cd-4787-82ba-39e73a750b14}]
@="Recent Files"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CLSID\{4564b25e-30cd-4787-82ba-39e73a750b14}\DefaultIcon]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,\
  00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,69,00,\
  6d,00,61,00,67,00,65,00,72,00,65,00,73,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,2d,\
  00,31,00,31,00,37,00,00,00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{4564b25e-30cd-4787-82ba-39e73a750b14}]
@="Recent Items Instance Folder"
"System.IsPinnedToNamespaceTree"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{4564b25e-30cd-4787-82ba-39e73a750b14}\Instance]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{4564b25e-30cd-4787-82ba-39e73a750b14}\Instance\InitPropertyBag]
"MaxItems"=dword:00000032
```

Screenshsots ( after removing `Type` & `Size` columns and adding `Link Target`  )

[image: Recent Folders]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this work perfectly. However, I would like these folders to also appear in Explorer file selector boxes. Do I need to create a separate entry in the Windows Registry ?

Answer (score 0):

Restore opened folders on login is more efficient via folder options settings in explorer.

https://www.windowscentral.com/how-restore-previous-folders-during-startup-windows-10

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read [How to reference material written by others](https://superuser.com/help/referencing). You must block quote text that has been written by some else. See [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help).