# How to sort Windows10 Quick Access recent files and folders" by date modified

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I would like to sort my Quick Access view of recent folders and recent files by date modified. But clicking the "date modified" column header does nothing and "sort by" and "group by" are inactive on the View menu.

Comment: You would probably find it beneficial to utilize the **Recent Items** folder to essentially do the same thing:  [History of opened folders in File Explorer](https://superuser.com/questions/1205241/history-of-opened-folders-in-file-explorer)

Comment: Thanks, I believe I used that a long time ago and didn't like it, but I don't recall why

Comment: You may want to consider it again, because I am fairly certain that you can't sort your Quick Access view of recent file and folders by date modified. Hopefully, someone else will come along and prove me wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The `Recent Items` folder (most easily displayed by typing `shell:Recent` in the `Run...` dialog or **Explorer** Address bar) is a sort of "raw data" repository --- shortcuts to files, folders, and searches all mixed together and all having a type of `Shortcut`, leaving the user with no way sort/group based on the ItemType of the shortcut *target*.

Fortunately, the sources for each section of `Quick Access`, `Frequent folders` and `Recent Items`, are also defined as virtual folders in the registry. In addition, there is a `Recent folders` folder defined as well -- an option many prefer over `Frequent folders`. With a little registry magic, these folders can be added to the Desktop/Navigation Pane, and the recent file list extended beyond the twenty-item limit of Quick Access.

[image]

The folders are defined in the registry under:

- `HKLM\Sofware\Classes\CLSID`

| CLSID | Items in folder |
| --- | --- |
| `{22877a6d-37a1-461a-91b0-dbda5aaebc99}` | Recent folders |
| `{3936E9E4-D92C-4EEE-A85A-BC16D5EA0819}` | Frequent folders |
| `{4564b25e-30cd-4787-82ba-39e73a750b14}` | Recent files |

Sinde these are already defined, only two things are *required* for the folders to appear in the Navigation Pane. THe folder needs to be added to the *Desktop Namespace* by creating a CLSID-named subkey under:

- `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\Namespace`

and a DWORD named `System.ISPinnedToNamespaceTree` with a value of `1` needs to be added to the base key.

These can be created under `HKCU` and they will combine with the entries under `HKLM` to produce the composite items that appear under `HKCR`. With a few values added for "window dressing" (icon, InfoTip, display name) and the `MaxITems` value bumped up to 50(decimal), the `.reg` file for `REcent files` looks like this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{4564b25e-30cd-4787-82ba-39e73a750b14}]
"System.IsPinnedToNamespaceTree"=dword:00000001
"LocalizedString"="Recent files"
@="Recent Items Instance Folder"
"InfoTip"="Extended list of recent files"
"System.HideOnDesktopPerUser"=""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{4564b25e-30cd-4787-82ba-39e73a750b14}\DefaultIcon]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,69,00,6d,00,\
  61,00,67,00,65,00,72,00,65,00,73,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,2d,00,31,\
  00,31,00,37,00,00,00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{4564b25e-30cd-4787-82ba-39e73a750b14}\Instance]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{4564b25e-30cd-4787-82ba-39e73a750b14}\Instance\InitPropertyBag]
"MaxItems"=dword:00000032

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\{4564b25e-30cd-4787-82ba-39e73a750b14}]
@="Recent files (extended)"

; A value of '1' hides the icon on tHe Desktop; a value of `0` displays it.

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\NewStartPanel]
"{4564b25e-30cd-4787-82ba-39e73a750b14}"=dword:00000000
```

You can copy and paste the above into **NOtepad** or any text editor, save with a `.reg` extension and close. Then right-ciick and `Merge`.

To add `Recent folders`, use the following `.reg` file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{22877a6d-37a1-461a-91b0-dbda5aaebc99}]
@="Recent folders"
"System.IsPinnedToNamespaceTree"=dword:00000001
"InfoTip"="Extended list of recent folders"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\{22877a6d-37a1-461a-91b0-dbda5aaebc99}]
@="Recent folders (extended)"

; A value of '1' hides the icon on tHe Desktop; a value of `0` displays it.

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\NewStartPanel]
"{22877a6d-37a1-461a-91b0-dbda5aaebc99}"=dword:00000000
```